# Removing the title of a tableview section in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder

When setting a table view to grouped in interface builder, is there a way to hide the 'title' heading?  It doesn't display on load, but it's making it difficult to arrange the other items on my view correctly (I have to overlap the items below with the the table view to get it to appear correctly).

EDIT

Here's what I mean:

[image]

You can see that I have had to place the label over the table (using trial and error), otherwise when the view is loaded (without the section header) there is a large gap.

Comment: NOt clear, can you provide the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't control what is shown in the mockup of the grouped UITableView in IB

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but I got stuck with same thing and figured it out.

In Interface Builder you need to change Table View Cell *Style* to **Custom**. Label will disappear.

Programmatically you **should not** use [UITableViewCell initWithStyle], but
init or initWithFrame.

Hope it is useful for someone.